# Want to create a keyvalue that can have nested pairs also

Tags: java

My xml looks like:

```
<node key="asdfasdf">value</node>
```

but may also be like:

```
<node key="asdf">
  <node key="2234">asdfsdf</node>
  <node key="223422"> qasdfljk</node>
</node>
```

99% of the time there is no nested key/value pairs, so how should I create a keyvalue class?
I guess I should lazy initialize the inner collection?

How should I define this class, should I inherit from SimpleEntry?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is a good idea:

```
public class Node {
    private String key;
    private String value;
    private List<Node> subNodes;

    //you can check if the node has subnode(s)
    private boolean hasSubNodes(){
        return !(subNodes == null || subNodes.isEmpty());
    }

    // if there is nested node, cannot call getValue 
    private String getValue(){
        if (hasSubNodes())
            throw new RuntimeException("blahblah");
        else
            return value;
    }

    //getters,setters are omitted

}
```

in this way you can have as many nesting as you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Guava Multimap, that collections represents what you need. 
http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/

Example:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

    final Multimap<String, Entry<String, String>> multimap = HashMultimap.create();
    multimap.put("asdfasdf", new NodeEntry(null, "value"));
    multimap.put("asdf", new NodeEntry("2234", "asdfsdf"));
    multimap.put("asdf", new NodeEntry("223422", "qasdfljk"));

    System.out.println(multimap);

}

class NodeEntry implements Entry<String, String> {

    private final String key;
    private final String value;

    public NodeEntry(final String key, final String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String setValue(final String value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("NodeEntry [key=").append(key).append(", value=").append(value).append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: can you help with some code? that's a confusing structure :)  I want a key/value pair, with the value being a list.  oh as I write this I'm kind of seeing what the multi map does hehe.

Comment: wait, the key is a string, and the value is a List<string,string>, how  will that work in java? (i'm a c# person)

Comment: I added an example. There is a previous answer which use a custom Node class. I'd say that depending on your need you should pick one of the other. E.g.: if you are going to mainly lookups/search/etc. Probably the Map solution might be easier to use.